# Flutter - Prevent custom draggable widget from being affected by a keyboard showing and hiding

Tags: flutter, widget, draggable

I've created a custom draggable widget in Flutter, for my app, which can be used anywhere, simply by using a stack and adding the widget on top of that stack. This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DraggableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Offset initialOffset;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final GlobalKey parentKey;

  const DraggableWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.initialOffset,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.parentKey,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DraggableWidgetState createState() => _DraggableWidgetState();
}

class _DraggableWidgetState extends State<DraggableWidget> {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  bool _isDragging = false;
  late Offset _offset;
  late Offset _minOffset;
  late Offset _maxOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _offset = widget.initialOffset;
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback(_setBoundary);
  }

  void _setBoundary(_) {
    final RenderBox parentRenderBox =
        widget.parentKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final RenderBox renderBox =
        _key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

    try {
      final Size parentSize = parentRenderBox.size;
      final Size size = renderBox.size;

      setState(() {
        _minOffset = const Offset(0, 0);
        _maxOffset = Offset(
            parentSize.width - size.width, parentSize.height - size.height);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('catch: $e');
    }
  }

  void _updatePosition(PointerMoveEvent pointerMoveEvent) {
    double newOffsetX = _offset.dx - pointerMoveEvent.delta.dx;
    double newOffsetY = _offset.dy - pointerMoveEvent.delta.dy;

    if (newOffsetX < _minOffset.dx) {
      newOffsetX = _minOffset.dx;
    } else if (newOffsetX > _maxOffset.dx) {
      newOffsetX = _maxOffset.dx;
    }

    if (newOffsetY < _minOffset.dy) {
      newOffsetY = _minOffset.dy;
    } else if (newOffsetY > _maxOffset.dy) {
      newOffsetY = _maxOffset.dy;
    }

    setState(() {
      _offset = Offset(newOffsetX, newOffsetY);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      right: _offset.dx,
      bottom: _offset.dy,
      child: Listener(
        onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent pointerMoveEvent) {
          _updatePosition(pointerMoveEvent);

          setState(() {
            _isDragging = true;
          });
        },
        onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent pointerUpEvent) {
          if (_isDragging) {
            setState(() {
              _isDragging = false;
            });
          } else {
            widget.onPressed();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          key: _key,
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, this does work really well when the screen dimensions are fixed/do not change. However, I have noticed a bug, whereby if the keyboard slides up on a phone (for a texfield input) this shrinks the widget moveable area. Then, when the keyboard is removed, instead of the widget seeing the whole screen area again, it only sees an area equivalent to when the keyboard was out. That means that where before the widget could be dragged all over the screen, it can now only be dragged within the total area of the screen minus the area of the keyboard, even when the keyboard has been closed/removed, almost like there's an imaginary boundary.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Essentially, the draggable widget needs to move around the whole screen when the keyboard is closed and when the keyboard is open, it needs to move around the area of the screen minus the area of the keyboard. When the keyboard is closed again, it needs to move around the whole screen again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it was actually happening because the draggable widget was being built before the preceding search delegate's keyboard had closed (this screen comprises a `SingleChildScrollView` widget with a number of modular stateful widgets as its children, one of which is a text button that calls a search delegate) so it took the height of the screen minus the keyboard height as the available height.

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution but I have managed to fix it by calling

```
final keyboardSize = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
```

in the build method, before returning the scaffold, which contained the stack (which itself contains the `SingleChildScrollView` and overlaid draggable widget).

Then, I made that keyboardSize parameter a required variable of the custom draggable widget and modified the `_maxOffset` parameter of the `_setBoundary(_)` function as follows:

```
_maxOffset = Offset(
  parentSize.width - size.width,
  parentSize.height - size.height + widget.keyboardSize,
);
```

This now seems to ensure that the draggable widget can be moved around the whole of the screen, not just the screen height minus the keyboard height.